# Why does a Haskell profiling graph indicate decreasing memory, when it keeps growing according to the OS?

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, memory-profiling

I, unfortunately, have a memory leak that is most likely <s>due to [my use of Conduit](https://www.well-typed.com/blog/2016/09/sharing-conduit/)</s> (see comment below). I tried out profiling for the first time, and ran the exe for about 30 minutes (maybe longer). During this time, according to `top`, the memory use steadily climbed to about 8 GB.

I canceled the execution with `Ctrl-C`, and received this message:

```
 207,273,173,680 bytes allocated in the heap
3,249,532,925,152 bytes copied during GC
   4,354,654,920 bytes maximum residency (1647 sample(s))
      43,810,104 bytes maximum slop
            4152 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     113916 colls,     0 par   26.122s  25.869s     0.0002s    0.0084s
  Gen  1      1647 colls,     0 par   4052.216s  4015.805s     2.4383s    7.0176s

  TASKS: 5 (1 bound, 4 peak workers (4 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0(0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.007s  (  0.008s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.000s  (-1697.639s elapsed)
  GC      time  2194.239s  (2175.089s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  PROF    time  1884.099s  (1866.585s elapsed)
  EXIT    time  1884.099s  (1866.586s elapsed)
  Total   time  4246.975s  (4210.628s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    0 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity -40.4% of total user, -40.3% of total elapsed
```

The resulting graph, generated by `hp2ps -e8in -c FarmDataServer.exe.hp`, only shows about 30 minutes, and actually shows a largely decreasing trend ... unless the graph isn't showing cumulative memory state but only allocations in a particular window of time?

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, I tracked down the actual problem, and it was neither the fault of GHC or of Conduit. It was me forgetting that several months ago, I had prototyped the code to read in an entire CSV file into memory. Now that I have much larger files, this is an issue. conduit-csv provides `intoCSV` for streaming reads.